# What happens to app.config in a referenced project

Tags: .net, app-config

Say I have 2 projects, where project A references project B. Project A is a web application project and project B is a class library.

The class library has an app.config file where some settings are stored. When I compile project A, projectB.dll is created in the bin folder.

What happens to the contents of the app.config file when the web application is deployed? Are the settings compiled into ProjectB.dll?

Is it possible to retrieve the contents of the app.config using a tool like reflector or ILSpy?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add an `app.config` to a library project, but it is *not used* or included in any of the output.

Configuration is meant to be done in the application - not in the library. So you need to put the configuration in question in the web.config of your web application, not in app.config of a library.

Comment: I realise that is the way its supposed to be done. I'm looking at a legacy project where the web references are in the class library :/ after looking through the code a bit further I see that the URLs of the web services are set programatically so the app.config settings aren't actually used. The original coder probably did this because of what you explained in your answer. thanks

Answer (score 4):

At runtime, your project B will use the settings of your web application project (the host). So you would have to recopy your settings in the web.config file.

Answer (score 3):

App.config is configuration, not application - so it's not saved into dll and it can't be displayed by reflector or decompiled.

You have to configure *Project B* with settings for *Project A* (in web.config as it is web app).

There is no mechanism to *automagicaly* configure external modules, unless they have coded default fall-back values.

Comment: I am having an issue where the class library is building the settings into the .dll from the app.config (created with the settings.setting UI), and when referencing the library, and calling Properties.Settings.Default..  it is using those settings, not the latest from the web.config in my ASP.NET MVC 4 project. Any idea?  This is my SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54219286/1794106

Answer (score 1):

App.config of your class library B becomes irrelevant. If you want to use data from there you should copy all the stuff to app.config of your parent application (in your case web.config). You will then be able to access contents of it using ConfigurationManager both from projects A and B