# How do I get my .NET library to inherit its configuration file settings from the requested app?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, config

I compile my .NET Library, and it creates `mylib.dll.config`.

But when I modify or even delete this file, it is clearly not being used.

My ASP.NET website has the exact same settings in it anyway, so is it possible to inherit the connection string?

That is, the .NET library inherits its connection string from my ASP.NET app configuration.

I call my settings from my library using:

```
mylib.Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnString;
```

or

```
Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnString;
```

My website has an identical setting:

```
myweb.Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnString;
```

The library is running off its compile time settings. Not the web settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At runtime the `mylib.dll.config` (created by your class library project) will be ignored and it's the `Web.config` that will be used.

That's the normal behavior for an asp.net web site.

It means that if you add something into your `.dll.config` file, you'd have to add it to the `Web.config` file as well.

See this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412116/what-happens-to-app-config-in-a-referenced-project/8412170).

Comment: The library using the settings that are in there at compile time. If I delete the settings, I can not compile (missing assembly reference). Changing webconfig had no effect to the library.

Comment: What kind of settings? You can keep the `.dll.config` in your project, what I mean is that it doesn't have to be deployed with your website.

Comment: my connection string. Ive put it back in. Check my update please. Maybe I reference it too strongly?

Comment: Oh I see, you can simply add your `connectionString` into the [corresponding node element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233.aspx) and use it with the `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"]` (reference `System.Configuration` assembly). See this [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2005/08/26/Using-connection-strings-from-web.config-in-ASP.NET-v2.0.aspx)

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnString"].ConnectionString` is causing problems. Actually `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myWeb.Properties.Settings.dbConnString"].ConnectionString` Works. Why do I need the whole thing? (This is what it is named as in my Config file- but in settings its just dbConnString). If I come to using it elsewhere (hence the lib), then it will problematic.

Answer (score 1):

Your library will use the configuration that is present in the configuration file for the executing assembly. In your case that is your `web.config` file of the ASP.NET web site.